# Tableau Hyperapi : Delete Row

Tags: java, tableau-api, hyper

I am trying to delete the first & last row with Java HyperAPI which i used to optimise big data into .hyper file. in tableau server. Im not sure if this possible but based on the documentation, some of the use cases i read , its possible

based on normal sql query , we can delete the first row with

```
delete top(1) from tablename
```

Script shown below is working fine which is able to remove row based on where condition

```
            long rowCountDeletedInCustomersTable = connection.executeCommand(
                    "DELETE FROM " + escapeName("Customer") +
                            "WHERE " + escapeName("Customer Name") + "=" + escapeStringLiteral("Dennis Kane")
            ).getAsLong();
```

however when i tried to delete the first with

```
long rowCountDeletedInCustomersTable = connection.executeCommand(
DELETE TOP(1) from " + escapeName("Customer")).getAsLong()
```

or

```
long rowCountDeletedInCustomersTable = connection.executeCommand(
DELETE FROM table WHERE ROWNUM = 1).getAsLong()
```

this will throw error, im not sure on which approach should i use

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you want to delete the "first" or "last" row from a Hyper file. Note that Hyper has no notion of "row order", so which row is considered to be the first/last row is somewhat random...

[Hyper's SQL syntax](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/hyper_api/en-us/reference/sql/sql.html) follows Postgres' conventions instead of Microsoft's SQL dialect. `DELETE TOP(1)` is a Microsoft-specific syntax.

Hyper doesn't have a corresponding syntax. But assuming you have a column `your_row_id` which forms a key for your relationship, you can use

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE your_row_id IN (SELECT your_row_id FROM tablename LIMIT 1)
```